# The flower "wavered" in the breeze or "quivered"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences

- Waver (verb): Move in a quivering way
- Quiver (verb): Tremble or shake with a slight rapid motion

What subtle difference is there, if any, between saying "the flower wavered in the breeze" and " the flower quivered in the breeze"?

Comment: Neither sounds very natural in this context. Quivering is something animate entities do out of cold or fear (like shivering or trembling). It’s a repetition of tiny shaking movements; wind doesn’t cause that. Wavering _can_ mean swaying or fluttering in the breeze and describe things like plants and leaves; but to me at least, that usage feels outdated. There are several verbs that suit your example better, such as _sway_, _flutter_ (perhaps better with leaves than with a flower), or simply _wave_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm afraid I disagree that _quiver_ only applies to animate beings, the Oxford online dictionary has [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quiver) which includes the example **the tree's branches stopped quivering** so they must think that trees can quiver.

Comment: @BoldBen I’ll bow to ODO, though I’ll say that that example sounds a bit odd to me as well, though not as odd as the flower quivering in the breeze. There’s a jittery, spasmodic quality to quivering which I can just about associate with the relative rigidity and motion of branches or twigs; but the soft pliability of a flower seems at odds with the idea of quivering to me.

Comment: Agreeing with both @JanusBahsJacquet's comments, I would say that "wavering", nowadays is used more in metaphorical senses -usually related to a change of mind or heart." e.g. "The British public appear to be wavering in their commitment to Brexit".

Comment: Idiomatic would be 'swayed' or 'trembled', words @BigBadCat suggests.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There might a a bit of US/UK difference in the usage, of course.

Answer (score 2):

*Waver* has more of a *swaying* connotation while *quiver* is more a *trembling* movement.

From [WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/quiver/waver):

> *As verbs the difference between quiver and waver is that quiver is to shake or move with slight and tremulous motion; to tremble; to quake; to shudder; to shiver while waver is to sway back and forth; to totter or reel.*

This means that in your example, "the flower wavered in the breeze" would give the picture of a flower gently waving, while "the flower quivered in the breeze" speaks more of a slight shaking or trembling.

I think that in this example, a flower *quivering* in the breeze does not sound right, because it does not accurately describe the normal motion of flowers in a breeze. There could be other examples, though, in which it would accurately describe a flower's motion.

Comment: _Quiver_ sounds quite odd with an inanimate entity like a flower as its subject, though—especially when the factor setting it in motion is a breeze. You quiver out of fear or cold, not from having the wind blow on you.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I agree that it would not generally be used like that, but in something like "The flower quivered from stem to petal as a fresh gust struck it" might work.

Comment: That might work, yes, but mainly because it anthropomorphises the flower, giving it the animate ability to shiver with cold as a freezing wind hits it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I agree with you, but I think _trembled_ can be used to describe a certain motion, as well as the action of trembling. I think "the leaves trembled in the turbulent rainforest air" also works, and is very similar to the OP's example, only in this case _trembled_ accurately describes the leaves' motion. I am not 100% sure though.